# Unable to Mock in Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, mocking, jestjs

I am trying to mock an API call using `jest.mock` method but `mockResolvedValue` give a compilation error
Do I need to make some other changes?

[image]

Comment: Please post text, not images of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ts-jest` test helper - [mocked](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/user/test-helpers#mocked).

> The mocked test helper provides typings on your mocked modules and even their deep methods, based on the typing of its source.

E.g.

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';

jest.mock('axios');

describe('61863621', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const users = [{ name: 'Bob' }];
    const resp = { data: users };
    mocked(axios.get).mockResolvedValue(resp);
    await expect(axios.get('http://localhost')).resolves.toEqual(resp);
  });
});
```

The outcome of the test:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61863621/index.test.ts (9.461s)
  61863621
    ✓ should pass (4ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.791s
```